# Retina image in signature on Windows Outlook remains blurry

Tags: html, outlook, signature, retina-display, retina

I just wasted some hours of my life trying to get an retina image to work in a Outlook signature on a Windows machine.

It does work on Mac Mail and on Mac Outlook. But with Outlook on Windows does the image keep getting blurry on the receiving end.

I added 96 DPI images, 300 DPI images. I used images with size x 2 AND original ones. All of them keep getting blurred.

I also tried code based solutions. You can CTRL + click on the signatures button in Outlook and then you can edit the .htm file. So I did. Added the following to the signature.htm file without success:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
```

So. People talk about it on forums. But it seem like there is no real solution to this problem, is there? Should we just accept that Outlook on windows doesn't support retina images in signatures? Or is there a solution after all?

Looking forward to hearing from you!